# How remove \ except if followed by a "?

Tags: regex

I need remove all \ in a string but only keep backslash followed by "

Example:

```
"comment": "Esquina/ Do Posto Ipiranga. Pen\última Casa Do Lado Esquerdo. Portão De Madeira Escrito \"Deus É Fiel\"",
```

to

```
"comment": "Esquina/ Do Posto Ipiranga. Penúltima Casa Do Lado Esquerdo. Portão De Madeira Escrito \"Deus É Fiel\"",
```

Comment: Those look like the same string with the exception of "Pen****última" being changed to "Penúltima". All the `\` characters appear to be the same.

Comment: Fixed the formatting so we can see the \ in the first string. But... your question says remove \, while your example also removes `*`. Can you adjust the question or the example so they match. Right now it's not clear what you really want.

Comment: Why do you care about escaped double quotes ? It's ridiculous because you don't understand what escape does. Maybe it's not an escaped double quote, maybe its `\\"`, maybe it's not inside quoted text. Don't you care about that ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression: `\\(?!")`. It should only match the character `\` when it isn't followed by `"`. That said, make sure the regex implementation you're using supports negative lookaheads (the `(?!...)` part of the regex)

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/YxcEGZ/1)